# Azure Error: data protection system cannot create a new key because auto-generation of keys is disabled

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-functions

I am trying to run an azure function on my local machine using Visual Studio Code. 
My *main.py* looks like this:

```
import logging

import azure.functions as func

def main(event: func.EventHubEvent):
    logging.info('Python EventHub trigger processed an event: %s', event.get_body().decode('utf-8'))
```

My *host.json* file looks like this:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[1.*, 2.0.0)"
  }
}
```

My *function.json* looks something like this:

```
{
  "scriptFile": "main.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "eventHubTrigger",
      "name": "event",
      "direction": "in",
      "eventHubName": "myhubName",
      "connection": "myHubConnection",
      "cardinality": "many",
      "consumerGroup": "$Default"
    }
  ]
}
```

The problem is when I run this, it throws me the following error:

> A host error has occurred at
>    Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection: An error occurred while trying to encrypt the provided data. Refer to the inner exception for more information. Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection: The key ring does not contain a valid default protection key. The data protection system cannot create a new key because auto-generation of keys is disabled.
>   Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: provider

I am not sure what I am I missing ? Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the Azure Storage account:

Make sure the *local.settings.json* has the correct credentials for the storage account

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "MyStorageKey",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, if you have solved this problem, you can mark your solution as the answer of the question. This will help others quickly identity where is the error come from.

Comment: Hi, Please note that stackoverflow does not allow me to accept my answer before two days of the original post, thus I need to wait for two days to pass then I can only accept my answer :)

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know it needs two days to wait. Thank you for your contribution.