# Azure Durable Function (Node.JS) error: System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException : Error occurred while trying to encrypt the provided data

Tags: node.js, asp.net-core, azure-durable-functions

Have an Azure Durable Functions App written in NodeJS. Functions are deploying fine to Azure but unable to debug them locally in VSCode due to the following error. I don't understand why I am getting a .NET core error in my app.

> MS_FUNCTION_LOGS 2,,,,ErrorOccuredDuringStartupOperation,Host.Startup,"System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException : An error occurred while trying to encrypt the provided data. Refer to the inner exception for more information.
> ---> System.InvalidOperationException : The key ring does not contain a valid default protection key. The data protection system cannot create a new key because auto-generation of keys is disabled.
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingProvider.CreateCacheableKeyRingCore(DateTimeOffset now,IKey keyJustAdded)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingProvider.Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.Internal.ICacheableKeyRingProvider.GetCacheableKeyRing(DateTimeOffset now)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingProvider.GetCurrentKeyRingCore(DateTime utcNow,Boolean forceRefresh)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingProvider.GetCurrentKeyRing()
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.Protect(Byte[] plaintext)    End of inner exception
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.Protect(Byte[] plaintext)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.DataProtectionCommonExtensions.Protect(IDataProtector protector,String plaintext)
> at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.DataProtectionKeyValueConverter.WriteValue(Key key) at D:\a\1\s\src\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\Security\KeyManagement\DataProtectionKeyValueConverter.cs : 59
> at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.KeyValueConverterFactoryExtensions.WriteKey(IKeyValueConverterFactory factory,Key key) at D:\a\1\s\src\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\Security\KeyManagement\KeyValueConverterFactoryExtensions.cs : 23    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.SecretManager.CreateKey(String name,String secret) at D:\a\1\s\src\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\Security\KeyManagement\SecretManager.cs : 608
> at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.SecretManager.GenerateKey(String name) at D:\a\1\s\src\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\Security\KeyManagement\SecretManager.cs : 601
> at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.SecretManager.GenerateHostSecrets() at D:\a\1\s\src\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\Security\KeyManagement\SecretManager.cs : 494
> at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.SecretManager.GetHostSecretsAsync() at D:\a\1\s\src\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\Security\KeyManagement\SecretManager.cs : 97
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.DefaultScriptWebHookProvider.GetOrCreateExtensionKey(String extensionName)
> at D:\a\1\s\src\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\WebHooks\DefaultScriptWebHookProvider.cs : 74

This same error is occurring when kicking off debugging on either windows or an ubuntu dev environment.

Azure Functions Core Tools Core Tools Version: 3.0.3904
Function Runtime Version: 3.3.1.0

local.settings.json details:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
      "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
      "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "node",
      "BlobStorageConnection": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",    
      "BlobStorageAccountKey": "",
      "CONTAINER_NAME": "downloads"
     }
}
```

Is there a way to change some configuration or flat to enable the key generation and auto-refresh of the crypto keys so that the system does this by itself and no need for the developer to interfere?

found a similar [question on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58588094/azure-error-data-protection-system-cannot-create-a-new-key-because-auto-generat) but not sure where to specify storage account details as my storage is set to the local emulator.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I upgrade `Azure Functions Core Tools` version to [`4.0.3971`](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2174087).

And also add `"AzureWebJobsSecretStorageType": "files"` in `local.settings.json` file. It works for me.

[image]